# How to loop in python Telegram bot conversation handler

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

bot doesn't come back to the start message after running once.

```
import logging
from config import TOKEN, hello_msg, key1_msg
import mysql.connector
from telegram.ext import Filters, ConversationHandler, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, 
Filters, Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent, 
InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update

CHOOSING, CHOOSING2 = range(2)


keyboard1 = [
[InlineKeyboardButton("Welcome Message", callback_data = 'welcome_Message')],
[InlineKeyboardButton("Commands", callback_data = 'Commands')],
[InlineKeyboardButton("Links to our website", callback_data = 'links_to_our_websites')],
[InlineKeyboardButton("Demo Try", callback_data = 'Demo_try')],
[InlineKeyboardButton("register", callback_data = 'register')],
[InlineKeyboardButton("Contact us", callback_data = 'Contact_us')]
]

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global up, cal
    up = update
    cal = CallbackContext
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id = update.effective_chat.id, text = hello_msg)
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard1)
    update.message.reply_text("please Choose: ", reply_markup = reply_markup)
    return CHOOSING

def button1(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    answer = query.data
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id = update.effective_chat.id, text = key1_msg[answer])
    return CHOOSING


def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    new = ConversationHandler(entry_points = [CommandHandler("start", start)], states = {CHOOSING : [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Welcome Message|Commands|Links to our website|Demo Try|register|Contact us)$'), start)]},fallbacks=[MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^start$'), sart)])

    dp.add_handler(new)
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button1))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to run the start command again right after a user will choose an option from a button...
I wanna learn how to pass parameters when giving handlers inside the conversation handler.
thank you.

Comment: Did you find answer to this question

Comment: as I remember I just put the start function inside button1 function. (you have to save update and context in a variable). then I directed to the next step through the conversation handler

Comment: Thanks @Maneth. I will try this approach.